# Filling element array using ternary - if undefined, replace it with string

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have an object array:

```
cost = [{ 
id: 'cost01', 
client: { id: 'client01', first_name: 'Max', last_name: 'Xam'}, 
status: 'failed'
}]
```

I'm trying to create a new array using the object above. When an element is undefined, replace it with the string 'N/A'

This is the code snippet:

```
const array = cost.map(
          (c: any) => ({
            data: [
              c.id,
              c.client.first_name +
                ' ' +
                c.client.last_name,
              c.total_price    // <--- this part is missing from cost 
                ? c.total_price
                : 'N/A',
              c.status
            ]
          })
        );
```

Notice that they array requires `c.total_price`, which the initial object `cost` does not have. So in this case `c.total_price` should be `undefined` and returns 'N/A'
But on the created array, `c.total_price` is missing

Returned array:

```
['cost01', 'Max Xam', 'failed'] -> array length 3
```

Expected result:

```
['cost01', 'Max Xam', 'N/A', 'failed'] -> array length 4
```

How can I modify the code above to reach the expected result? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You doesn't need ternary operator(?).
Just use nullish coalescing(??) or logical OR(||)

```js
const cost = [{ 
id: 'cost01', 
client: { id: 'client01', first_name: 'Max', last_name: 'Xam'}, 
status: 'failed'
}];

const result = cost.map(c=>{
  const data = [c.id,
  c.client.first_name +' ' +c.client.last_name,
  c.total_price ?? "N/A",
  c.status,
  ]
  return {
    data
  }
});

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. You can use ?? or ||, as Yuvraj mentioned.

```js
const cost = [{ 
id: 'cost01', 
client: { id: 'client01', first_name: 'Max', last_name: 'Xam'}, 
status: 'failed'
}]


const array = cost.map(
          (c) => ({
            data: [
              c.id,
              c.client.first_name +
                ' ' +
                c.client.last_name,
              c.total_price    // <--- this part is missing from cost 
                ? c.total_price
                : 'N/A',
              c.status
            ]
          })
        );
console.log(array)
```